# Objects detected by Livequery in ie7

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7, livequery

Can anyone figure out why this gives me blank alert boxes in ie7?

```
$("#bottles a").livequery("click", function(event) {  
    thetitle=$(this).attr("title");  
    alert(thetitle);  
    return false;  
});
```

For each new A tag loaded, ie7 alerts a blank message (FF correctly shows the respective titles) However, when thetitle= $(this).html(), ie7 alerts the correct information. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector and accessor are overkill for that.  Have you tried this?

```
$("#bottles a").livequery("click", function(event) {  
        // Always define a local variable, unless you explicitly 
        //  want your variable to be globally scoped.
        var thetitle = this.title;  

        alert(thetitle);

        return false;  
});
```

On a separate note, did you know that [jQuery 1.3.x has LiveQuery built in](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn)?  No need for the additional plugin anymore.